# Converting a column that is a series of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCyVs.png)

I'm trying to convert the column 'Ambience' from the Yelp Dataset so it can the values can be spread out over a column in Dataframe. Tried several differnet things but it still did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , assuming you have already preprocessed till `df3` as shown in the image

Since `Ambience` Column contains dictionaries , you can create 2 additional columns from its key and values

Further More you can explode the resultant Dataframe using [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
import numpy as np

def parse_dict(inp,return_key='key'):
    if inp:
       if return_key='key':
          return sorted(inp.keys())
       else:
          return sorted(inp.values())
    else:
       return np.nan


df3['Ambience_Key'] = df3.loc[:,'Ambience'].apply(lambda x: parse_dict(x,return_key='key'),axis=1)

df3['Ambience_Value'] = df3.loc[:,'Ambience'].apply(lambda x: parse_dict(x,return_key='value'),axis=1)

df3.explode('Ambience_Key')
```

**Note - This is not the best of the solutions , but intention here is to get you started with something**

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for helping. I tried copy pasting the code you have but I still got an error. It says <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Try to go through this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878720/dataframe-apply-doesnt-accept-axis-argument